# Meaning of "To be difficult by oneself"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I came across this phrase on the Internet:

> I won't put up with your nonsense. You can be difficult by yourself.

I cannot understand what it means "to be difficult by yourself". Does it mean that "You can't even deal with yourself".

Thanks in advance

Comment: Basically the same as going into a room by yourself, closing the door, and dealing with your (supposed) nonsense. Basically "keep it to yourself".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'difficult' in this sentence does not mean the usual literal meaning of the word *'difficult'*. This sentence means:

> "You can be a a pest (a pain in the a**), by yourself. You can be whatever you want, alone, because I can't put up with your behavior. I'm leaving you."

The *'difficult'* refers to '[**A difficult person**](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110418165747AAJF2Sg)', which means:

> Somebody who has certain personality or emotional traits which make very difficult to communicate with.

and '*by yourself*' simply means '**alone**'.